# how to reinstall graphics driver

Tags: windows-8, drivers, graphics-card

I uninstalled my graphics driver because of .dll errors.
Now my laptop can't see my graphics card, it's not listed in the Device Manager. When I try to install another driver it says my laptop does not have the hardware:
Dell Lattitude E6530
NVIDIA 5200M
Windows 8

I tried [downloading drivers](ftp://ftp.dell.com/Pages/Drivers/latitude-e6530.html) and [detecting them](http://www.nvidia.com/Download/Scan.aspx).

Comment: Have you removed the device in the device manager within windows?

Comment: No and I tried detect hardware, that does nothing. I mean that the graphics card is not listed in the Device Manager.

Comment: Try removing the device or clarify what the device manager displays with a screenshot

Comment: The device is not listed in the device manager.

Comment: Try downloading from nVidia.com

Comment: Did that, the installation wizard says my laptop does not have the required hardware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

1. Open `Add Hardware`(Type in dialog box, `Hdwwiz.exe` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>).
2. Press `Next`.
3. Select **`Install the hardware that I manually select from a list (Advanced)`**.

Select `Video Adapters`.

[image]

In the list of `Manufacturers` see if you can see `Nvidia`, if so the list next select the model of your graphics card and click `Next`.

[image]

---

If all else fails, install an Intel driver and then nVidia drivers.

Comment: The automatic detector only sees the onboard Intel graphics card.

Comment: @MrFox Updated the answer, see now.

Comment: Turns out my intel driver was also broken, reinstalling it allowed me access to the dedicated graphics card. Also there was a problem with the driver connecting the dedicated card to the motherboard, that was fixed by an automatic windows fixer http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725584(v=ws.10).aspx.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download the driver from support.dell.com and select the correct model. Do not use the "Detection" method because it leads to false positives.

If you know the exact card your computer shipped with then select the Operating System.
If you're using Windows, you will need to know if it's 32-bit or 64-bit.

If this fails, you may need an expert to go thru the registry to remove all traces of the graphic card and it's drivers.

Microsoft has this article that gives you the registry locations

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/200435

Like always, back up your stuff when making changes as it may cause your system to stop booting.

If your PC is under warranty, have Dell fix it for you. They can help you remotely. OR go to a Microsoft Store if one is near your home.